# remove last character after line break

Tags: vb.net

basically what my function what to achieve is to separate each of column data in dataset clearly

```
Public Shared Function mtdCDsToStr (ByVal pDs As DataSet) As String

Dim sResult As String = " "
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim dc As DataColumn
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim i As Integer = 0

For Each dt In pDs.Tables
 For Each dr In dt.Rows
  For Each dc In dt.Columns
    sb.Append(dr(i).ToString + "|" + Environment.NewLine )

  Next

  sb.Remove(sb.Length -1, 1)
 Next
Next
sResult = sb.ToString
End Function
```

so my return result will be something like

**Result**
Name1|
Name2|
Name3|
Name4|

| is my data separator, i was trying to remove the | if reached the last record but i failed to make it

**Expected Result**
Name1|
Name2|
Name3|
Name4

there are no | in my last record

Comment: And when you reset I to 0?

Comment: sorry oscar, what do u means? u means the counter i?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it's never reset to 0. Maybe not relevant, or maybe yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

To remove | and new line.

```
sb.Remove(sb.Length -1 - Environment.NewLine.Length, Environment.NewLine.Length + 1)
```

Just to remove |

```
    sb.Remove(sb.Length -1 - Environment.NewLine.Length, 1)
```

Comment: genius, give u a likes , xD

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For Each dt In pDs.Tables
 For Each dr In dt.Rows
  For Each dc In dt.Columns
    sb.Append(dc(i).ToString + iif(i=dt.Columns.Count-1,"","|") + Environment.NewLine )
    i += 1
  Next      
 Next
Next
sResult = sb.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You just replace

```
sb.Append(dr(i).ToString + "|" + Environment.NewLine )
```

with

```
 dim j as Integer = 0 // declare this above all the loops

 if j < dt.Columns.Count - 1 Then
     sb.Append(dr(i).ToString + "|" + Environment.NewLine )
```

I think it will help, because it will check if it is not the last column then only it will execute the statement else it will not execute.

Just try and i hope it will help.. :)